# Showing that a function is strictly increasing in $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Assume that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and $f'$ exists and is positive for all but, at most a finite number of points in $(a,b)$, prove that $f$ is strictly increasing  on $(a,b)$.

Attempted solution: let $x_1,x_2 \in  (a,b)$ such that $x_1\lt x_2$.
If $f$ is continuos  on $[x_1,x_2]$ and $f'$ is exists and positive on $[x_1,x_2]$,
by the Mean value theorem there exist $c\in(x_1,x_2) $ such that 
$$f'(c)=\frac {f (x_2)-f (x_1)}{x_2-x_1} $$
and
$$0\lt f'(c)=\frac {f (x_2)-f (x_1)}{x_2-x_1} $$
 Then $0 \lt f (x_2)-f (x_1)$, that is $f (x_1)\lt f (x_2) $.
So $f$ is strictly increasing  on $(a,b)$.

What is wrong with this proof?  Thanks in advance

Comment: And what if the derivative does not exist on $[x_1,x_2]$?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing *wrong* with the proof, but it's only half-way done. As you said, the inequality you wrote is only proven **if $f'$ exists on $[x_1,x_2]$.** Now you need to address the other options.

**Hint**:

1. You only need $f'$ to exists on $(x_1,x_2)$ for your part of the proof to work.
2. Split the interval $[x_1,x_2]$ into (finitely many) subintervals on which $f'$ exists and repeat your reasoning on each.